# How to obtain drawable of BoundingBox with specified zoom?

Tags: android, osmdroid

I got some BoundingBox (which actually is north-west-south-west coords) from map view and now I would like to draw that bounding box with some zoom level at my view.

I know that I may get list of tile ids to cover specified area with zoom (`org.osmdroid.tileprovider.cachemanager.CacheManager#getTilesCoverage(org.osmdroid.util.BoundingBox, int)`) and I know how to get drawable of tile by id (`org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.IFilesystemCache#loadTile`)
So now I can concat drawables manually and crop to my bounding box but I assume that there are simplest way to do it.

Comment: ??? Could you explain (in simple words) what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to get image (bitmap) from map by coordinates and zoom level